# Allow pagination in single custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I registered a custom taxonomy 'genre' and created a custom template taxonomy-genre.php

the link:

website.com/genre/comedy

works perfectly but

website.com/genre/comedy/page/2

gives me 404 error. I dump $wp_query and I get:

```
public 'query' => 
  array (size=2)
    'paged' => string '2' (length=1)
    'genre' => string 'comedy' (length=6)
```

So the query is correctly understanding that we're looking for the taxonomy genre "comedy" in page 2, but for some reason is not loading the correct template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything is working except for the pagination, it sounds like you don't have enough posts with that category to have a page 2.

With any pagination in Wordpress (not just for custom taxonomies), you will get a 404 error if you try to access a page number that doesn't exist - it's the same as accessing any page that doesn't exist.

**Example:**
if you have 15 uncategorised posts and show 10 posts per page (i.e. enough for 2 pages of posts), you will get the following:

- website.com/category/uncategorized/ - *shows posts 1-10*
- website.com/category/uncategorized/**page/2/** - *shows posts 11-15*
- website.com/category/uncategorized/**page/3/** - *404 error: There are not enough posts for a third page*

(Apologies for the simplistic example! I'm sure you understood, but I thought I'd include it for others with less experience who may have the same problem)